# convert sql to Laravel Query Builder ->where('b.seq','=',DB::raw('select max(seq) from sells_2020 where pa_no=a.pa_no'))

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

i have sql query which works as expected in raw sql but not in query builder

```
 where  a.price = '399' and 
              b.seq=(select max(seq) from sells_2020 where pa_no=a.pa_no) 
              order by  a.pa_no
```

this works fine in sql but not in Query builder
i try this ,

```
->where('a.price',399)
  ->where('b.seq','=',DB::raw('select max(seq) from sells_2020 where pa_no=a.pa_no'))
               ->OrderBy('a.pa_no')
```

So how can i convert this to query builder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you just have to add parentheses like you did in raw sql, and the orderBy
starts with small 'o'.

now you inner raw sql query should return one result:

```
->where('a.price',399)
  ->where('b.seq','=',DB::raw('(select max(seq) from sells_2020 where pa_no=a.pa_no)'))
               ->orderBy('a.pa_no')->get();
```